# a single estimate and the population mean

Tags: confidence-interval, sum

There is a physical parameter $Z$ defined as $Z=\frac{X}{X+Y}$,
where $X=\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i$ and $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{N} y_i$.

I want to find an interval that brackets the population mean $\mu_Z$ for a specific $N$.
I guess normally one would perform repeated sampling, find $\bar{Z}$ and put the confidence bounds on $\bar{Z}$ that would bracket $\mu_Z$: $\bar{Z}\pm t\frac{s_Z}{\sqrt{m}}$.

However, when the measurements of $Z$ are performed in the field, they are usually limited to a single estimate of $Z$ based on a single measurement of $X=\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i$ and $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{N} y_i$, where $N$ can vary from 50 to 300 depending on a field survey.

The question is whether we can somehow use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ contain multiple measurements of $x$ and $y$ to draw conclusions about $\mu_Z$ based on a single estimate of $Z$.

If I understand correctly, in accordance with the Central Limit theorem, a sum of $N$ identically distributed random variables with a mean $\mu$  and a variance $\sigma^2$  for a large $N$ converges to a normal distribution with the mean $N\mu$  and the variance $N\sigma^2$. Thus, if $N$ is large enough, then $\mu_X =N\mu_x$ , $\mu_Y =N\mu_y$ and $\sigma_X^2 =N\sigma_x^2$, $\sigma_Y^2 =N\sigma_y^2$, meaning that for a large $N$ $\sigma_Z$ can be found as:

$\sigma_Z=\sqrt\frac{\mu_x^2\sigma_y^2+\mu_y^2\sigma_x^2}{N}\frac{1}{(\mu_x+\mu_y)^2}$
(with uncertainty propagation rules applied).

So theoretically we can find $\sigma_Z$ even if we have only one estimate of $Z$, using $\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$, $s_x$ and $s_y$ as the best estimates of $\mu_x$, $\mu_y$, $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$.

Is there any chance that we can use this $\sigma_Z$ and the single estimate of $Z$ to make assumptions about the population mean, $\mu_Z$?

Thank you a lot in advance for any suggestions

Comment: NB: the distribution of $Z$ is assumed to be approximately normal

Comment: If the $x_i$ and $y_i$ could be positive or negative, your question becomes problematic and more information would be welcome.  If instead they are non-negative, then perhaps a more useful approximation (for the purpose of this analysis) would be that they follow *Gamma* distributions, for the sums $X$ and $Y$ would be Gammas and consequently [the ratio $Z$ would have a Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Derived_from_other_distributions). The plausibility of these assumptions could be checked by examining the individual $x_i$ and $y_i$.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for the comment. $x_i$ and $y_i$ are indeed non-negative. The distribution of $x_i$ can be well fitted by a Gamma distribution, the distribution of $y_i$ is a bit trickier, though. It has too prominent peak value, which is not really typical of a Gamma distribution (unfortunately, I can not attach figures here)

Comment: Gamma distributions can have prominent peaks: choose a large shape parameter and a scale parameter inversely proportional to that. What matters is whether the scale parameters for the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are approximately the same or not.  If they are, the analysis is easy (as I sketched); if they are not, it's harder.

Comment: @whuber, MLE gave $x \sim Gamma(1.02, 0.21)$, $y \sim Gamma(2.14, 0.16)$. However, I still doubt that the Gamma distribution is a good choice for $y$. I can not use the KS test to check whether the Gamma distribution assumption is correct, because I have estimated the shape and the scale parameters based on my data, or can I?

Comment: You don't want to test: you just want to see whether these could be useful starting points for making approximations. If your standard errors are large enough, the scale of $0.21$ might not be really different from $0.16$, in which case all you need to check is that these distributions (fit using a *common* scale parameter) describe the $x_i$ and $y_i$ data reasonably well without enormous outliers. If that's the case, it would look worthwhile modeling $Z$ with a Beta distribution and you can estimate its parameters from the fits to $X$ and $Y$. I trust the $x_i$ and $y_j$ are independent!

Comment: @whuber,thank you for pointing out the beta distribution,it would be a neat solution to the problem. However, unfortunately, $y$ and $x$ cannot be fitted with a Gamma distribution with the same scale parameter. I've performed simulations on several objects, 200 $Z$ estimates were calculated based on $N$=10,20,50,100,300 measurements of $x$ and $y$.Also the population means $\mu_Z$ were found for each object.All $Z$ estimates appeared to be quite normally distributed (judging by qq plots and the results of the KS tests).

Comment: When I gave each individual estimate of $Z$ the margins=$\pm3\sigma_Z$,where $\sigma_Z$ was calculated as suggested in the question,the population mean was covered by these margins in more than 95%of the cases(100% refers to 200 $Z$ estimates).As I'm a novice in statistics,can you please advice whether one can place margins on individual estimates(I have a feeling that it's $generally$ not correct,because the standard deviation of the population is usually unknown, however, this case is quite special,because we can estimate the$\sigma_Z$ even though we have only one $Z$measurement)